# Android List view row move vertical

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

I want to create List view row animation like below . I want to move row from one list view to other list view. Both list view are in same activity. 
[image]
Anyone can give me idea how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all because you mentioned "`ListView`":
In my opinion the best way to perform dynamic "lists" in android is to use to android-given class 
[RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).
It's easy to use like a normal `ListView` but like I said before it handles dynamic data.
Moreover it has some support librarys like `ItemTouchHelper` to drag/drop and swipe items in the list around. Its very easy to expand your RecyclerView with this upgrade. Here is a good tutorial:

[Tutorial](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.k48dvorla).

I would like to give you two ideas how I would proceed to implement such a list like the example of your post:

1) (Recommended) Search on Github or similar sites for 3rd library parties that already solved this.

2) Use the RecyclerView with the ItemtouchHelper-Upgrade i mentioned above and try to expand it with two lists. When an item is onMove() set the visibility of the first list on GONE and the second on VISIBLE. Now you only have to add the data of your item to the second list and remove it from the first. Then use `notifyDataSetChanged()` on both lists and your done.

I dont know how difficult it will be to implement it but thats the only way I know how you can do that and how the programmers of your example could have done it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I will try this.